ASP.NET Core API AntiforgeryToken 400 Bad Request
To call the API with the AntiforgeryToken applied, I wrote an HttpClient like this.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PhoneNumberAuth(int app_idx, string memberPhone)
{
....
....
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string url = "https://" + HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString() + Url.Action("PhoneNumberAuth", "Api")!;

AntiforgeryTokenSet requestTokenSet = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
string requestTokenHeaderName = requestTokenSet.HeaderName!;
string requestToken = requestTokenSet.RequestToken!;

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(requestTokenHeaderName, requestToken);

var authenticationNumber = new
{
    receiveNumber = memberPhone,
    senderNumber = smsInfo.sms_phoneNumber
};

string dataJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authenticationNumber);
StringContent content = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

return Ok();

}

However, this will result in a 400 Bad Request error.
If I apply the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute to the API, I will get a 200 OK instead of an error.
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PhoneNumberAuth()
{
...
    return Ok();
}

Note that the two PhoneNumberAuth Methods exist in different Controllers.
Why is the error occurring?
In the View, I call the PhoneNumberAuth(int app_idx, string memberPhone) Method via Javascript, which in turn calls the PhoneNumberAuth API.
I don't call the PhoneNumberAuth API directly because we need to handle sensitive information.
I can't apply the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute and I can't create such an Action Method.

Can a token go wrong?
View handled it like this
@{
    var requestToken = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context);
}
...
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("PhoneNumberAuth", "Api")',
    headers:
    {
        '@requestToken.HeaderName': '@requestToken.RequestToken'
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
                            
    },
    error: function(ajaxContext) {
                            
    }
});

To call this in the Controller's Action Method(PhoneNumberAuth(int app_idx, string memberPhone)), I wrote the following in cs.
private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

public SiteController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    _antiforgery = antiforgery;
}
...
AntiforgeryTokenSet requestTokenSet = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);

Am I missing something in this code?

Can you try HttpContext.Request.Host.Value?

Yes, but the result is the same.

We can judge from your description that there is something wrong with your token retrieved from httpcontext. Since you cannot modify your Api method or create a new action ,there are solutions to modify the token. However first is to debug what is the error. You need to verify is the token is correct or missing. Is the token expired, does the header match. Provide more debug information to find out the causes.

"I don't call the PhoneNumberAuth API directly because we need to handle sensitive information."  (?!)  Why would an HTTP request be more secure?  It doesn't make sense, to me at least, to make a call to the same server.  You're just adding overhead.  Right now, though, you're not passing the cookie that the anti-forgery value would be checked against.

so normally GetAndStoreTokens would set a cookie in the response. The token is then decrypted on the next request using a rotating key to see if it matches that cookie. (you might be able to get that cookie from the tokenset... requestTokenSet.CookieToken. Then add the cookie to the request.... just check to be sure that's actually different than RequestToken... that might also be the encrypted value)

so normally the cookie it checks against is set when the session has begun.  In this way it is tied to the session.  This value doesn't change.  The anti-forgery token changes per response and then is expected on the next request.  (the encryption key rotates)  That ties it not only to the session but also to the form.

The reason I want to change from calling the API in javascript to calling it in an Action Method is because I want to handle sensitive data that shouldn't be exposed in Javascript.  First of all, it's true that the token value is different, so we get a 400 Bad Request. I need to find a way to pass a valid Token value in the Action Method.

I was reading that as server-side code and since you're setting the URL to the request.host, that would be same server.  Any reason you can't call the method directly?

if the CookieToken value and RequestToken are different, than you probably have what you need to send the http request (but I still don't understand why that's necessary)  Just be sure to include the cookie in the request.  (it's going to try do decrypt the RequestToken to match the cookie...)  The way you implement IAntiForgery doesn't really look correct, though... usually you'd get that from the service injected on startup.

The reason I want to use the API is because other applications use the same API. There's no reason why I can't use it directly in my Method, but I want to have the same functionality together.

you could make that into a helper function and import where needed.

Please note that there's no need to apply Anti-Forgery Token protection to protect against CSRF attacks in ASP.NET CORE web API.
If you'd like to secure and protect your APIs, you can try to integrate such Token-based etc authentication and authorization mechanism into your API project.
If you indeed want to implement AntiforgeryToken validation with your API endpoint, you can refer to the following example code.
// Add Antiforgery services
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});

//...

Controller and Action
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public ValuesController(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetToken")]
    public IActionResult GetToken()
    {
        var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
        return Ok(new { token = tokens.RequestToken });
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost("[Action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PhoneNumberAuth()
    {
        //...
        return Ok("success");
    }

    //...

Example and test requests
###
# get token
GET  https://localhost:7014/api/values/GetToken HTTP/1.1

###
# make request with XSRF token
POST https://localhost:7014/api/values/PhoneNumberAuth HTTP/1.1
X-XSRF-TOKEN: CfDJ8KmhRjRu7cpNjZEYjJecX1dG8RozjhyUrthrU0kNYV-9auYN47VfKORxLOo_9G78ElX14Wcx2kQmXn9tJiRSIj6REVu0c2Z1iENmm7BaBwmxxGyB_hB2L2olrRKSY3ZeZS8Bl44eU6OS0zkho4FZKAE

Test Result

